# How can javascript rewrite <a href=#x> to be absolute based on the current URL location instead of relative because we are using <base>?

Tags: javascript, html, tags, href, anchor

If I have a page http://www.example1.com/foo/test.html as follows:

```
<head>
<base href=http://www.example2.com/>
</head>
<body>
<a href=#foo>foo</a>
...
<a name=foo />
</body>
```

Then when I click "foo" it takes me to http://www.example2.com/#foo instead of http://www.example1.com/foo/test.html#foo .

Question:

- How do I write an onClick hook (or similar) so that the href is re-written to be absolute to the current page so that it goes to the "correct" location of http://www.example1.com/foo/test.html#foo ?

Comment: Put `"//" + location.hostname + location.pathname` in front of the href.

Comment: @ChrisG, It sounds like you meant this, but I don't think I understood: <a href='"//"+location.hostname+location.pathname+"#foo"'>foo</a>

Comment: This works: onclick='this.href="//"+location.hostname+location.pathname+"$2"' .  Do you know if this should be nice and cross-browser?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to write a function that reads the `href` attribute and puts the other stuff on front of it, then to assign that to all <a> elements in question. Not a fan of inline code to be honest. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/7nafov29/

Comment: @ChrisG, agreed, code is better!  Do you want to write up the answer, or shall I copy-paste it in?